# Inject JavaScript code into websites requested by an Android app?

Tags: web-browser, xss, android

How can I add custom scripts to pages I'm opening on Android via Chrome, Firefox or any other internet browsing app?

Comment: Could you provide more details? It's your app, or another app? On your phone, or another person's phone?

Comment: Perhaps you should [edit](https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/197812/edit) the question to read "On my desktop I would do ... blah blah, ... but on Android this doesn't work because .. blah blah. How do I do this on Android?"

Answer (score 1):

My best bet would be to just browse the web through a proxy that injects the script for you. On a desktop you can just use the developer console or a browser extention, but that's not an option on mobile.

Note that this is not really a way to "hack" someone, since the only person it affects is yourself.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want. Just for myself. Can I host a proxy directly on my phone?

Comment: @The_javascript_King I don't know what the best way to set up a proxy is, but I guess you'll need to run the proxy on a desktop you connect through or something similar.